# Resolving F# assembly references

Tags: visual-studio, f#, nuget, azure-functions, rider

In both Rider and Visual Studio, I'm having issues getting F# to recognise the Newtonsoft.Json dependency.

I have in import of `#r "Newtonsoft.Json"`, and have used NuGet to add it to my project, but it's not affecting the highlighted error:

Assembly reference "Newtonsoft.Json" was not found or was invalid.

I'm just trying out F# for the first time, so this is probably a very simple issue, but I couldn't find a reference to it anywhere online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, eventually I found an answer for this, posted by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp).

> An editor that supports F# Compiler Services will not be aware of the namespaces and assemblies that Azure Functions automatically includes. As such, it can be useful to include a prelude that helps the editor find the assemblies you are using, and to explicitly open namespaces.

For example:

```
#if !COMPILED
#I "../../bin/Binaries/WebJobs.Script.Host"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll"
#endif

open System
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host

let Run(blob: string, output: byref<string>, log: TraceWriter) =
...
```

So in my case:

```
#if !COMPILED
#I "../bin"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
#endif
```

Comment: I hope you realize that it is only a problem if you use scripts in Azure Function? :) This is neither a problem for precompiled F# assemblies in Azure Function nor a problem for usual F# scripting. Moreover `COMPILED` constant defined by AF Runtime. Now look at your question - no one could help you with description you gave because your problem is Azure Function shenanigans. Not F#

Answer (score 1):

`#r` is being used in F# script files `.fsx`

To make it work you should pass relative or absolute path to dll like this:

```
#r @"C:\Users\USER_NAME\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
//or
#r @"..\packages\Newtonsoft\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
//or
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" //assumes that dll and .fsx file are in the same folder
```

You could also create usual F# project file `.fsproj` (Rider and VisualStudio could help with that), which utilizes usual `.fs` files.

If these `.fs` files are part of `.fsproj` (`Compile` section) you could use namespaces from your nuget as usual (`open` directives) without `#r` dll links.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-visual-studio) tutorial to create project in VS

Comment: Your first suggestion would break platform independence though, wouldn't it?

Also, interesting to note that this is code autogenerated by Azure, and that it is generated with a .csproj file, which does reference the Newtonsoft assembly.

Comment: Note also that I have the same problem if I start a project from scratch in Rider, put a reference to Newtonsoft.Json in it, and then attempt to add the reference in the NuGet tool window.

Comment: @a000h to make somewhat platform independent you should use relative path and a way to provide dll with that relative path (`dotnet restore`, `paket install` etc)

Comment: @a000h Azure functions with script files (`.csx`, `.fsx`) are a magic box. Azure Function runtime makes a ton of moves to make your script files work, so it is very special case which you should mention in your question.